# Telethon, catch_up(), get images

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to use the catch_up() function to get all file updates on boot, however, everytime I run my code, only half of the file is downloaded, sometimes the file is completely empt.

However, when I try to run with "iter_messages" I manage to download everything perfectly.

HELP!?

```py
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def new_messages(event):
    if hasattr(event.message.peer_id, "channel_id"):
        print("Um dos canais");
    else:
        if hasattr(event.message.peer_id, 'chat_id'):
            print("Tipo: ","chat");
            dialog = int(event.message.peer_id.chat_id);

        else:
            print("Tipo: ","conversa");
            dialog = int(event.message.peer_id.user_id)

        '''getting the files'''
        path = ""
        if hasattr(event.media, "document"):
            print("================\n", event.message.id, "\n================");
            path = await client.download_media(event.media, file="arquivos_chimera/");
            print(event)

        if hasattr(event.media, "photo"):
            print("================\n", event.message.id, "\n================");
            path = await client.download_media(event.media, file="imagens_chimera/")
            print(event)

        '''getting the Telegram date'''
        data = str(event.message.date);

        '''text of the message'''
        temp_message = await async_ajuste_SQL(event.message.message);
        if path != "":
            temp_message = path + " - " + temp_message;

        '''Quem enviou a mensagem'''
        if event.message.from_id==None:
            from_ = event.message.peer_id.user_id;

        else:
            from_ = event.message.from_id.user_id

            cur.execute(f"insert into tabela_de_mensagens values ({event.message.id}, {dialog}, {from_}, '{data}', '{temp_message}', 0);");
            con.commit();

async def main():
     await client.catch_up();
```

NOTE: the problem only ocurrs to images, delete, edit and new message updates come perfectly

Answer (score 0):

So, after some testing, I realized that the problem was the fact that I was using an event handler without using a keep alive function, i.e., the event handler only works while the main function works, so, if you try to run the event handler with catch_up **alone**, it will only get the first updates, but will stop shortly after that (hence, why my image files were created, but not completed).

To get a solution, you can look at the following links:

- https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/1534
- https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/3146
- https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait